# how to prove that $f(x) = \ln (x^2 +1 )$ is not uniform continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, logarithms, uniform-continuity

$f:[0, +\infty) \to \Bbb{R}$

[image]`

It is the last function in the photo. 
I couldn't find two Sequences that will prove that and also couldn't find a proof for saying that because $x^2 +1$ is not uniformly continuous, therefore $\ln( x^2 +1)$ is also not uniformly continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ f(x)=log(1+x^2)$. Note that $$|f'(x)|=|2x/(1+x^2)|\le 1$$ for all real numbers $x$. Therefore $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)(x-y)|\le |x-y|$. Thus f(x) is uniformly continuous.

Comment: how did you come up with that that 1 is a bound for the function? (this is of course true, but i'm interested in the Technic.

Comment: The critical points of $2x/(1+x^2)$are x=1 and x=-1.  Absolute Maximum of 1 is attained at  x=1 and absolute minimum of -1 is attained at x=-1.

Answer (score 6):

But it is! 
$$
|\log(1+x^2)-\log(1+y^2)|\stackrel{\text{mean value theorem}}\leq |x-y|\sup_{t\in [0,\infty)}\left|\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right|=|x-y|
$$

Comment: I am not the OP, but could you elaborate more on the first inequality? Just curious since this looks interesting :)

Comment: it comes from the mean value theorem. That difference is equal to $|x-y|$ times some value of the derivative of the function between $x$ and $y$. But the derivative is bounded on the whole domain

Comment: If you use the MVT, at least mention it in your proof!

Comment: It looks like a quick sketch or a hint, not a fully detailed-proof, so its totally fine to leave out stuff in my opinion.

Comment: I don't fully understand this solution. As this is a part of homework in the course on calculaus 1a, is there a different way to solve this question without using the derivative?

Comment: It it not a hint unless you say so. If you intended it as a hint, it is a very odd one. A better one would have just said Hint: Show $f'$ is bounded and use the MVT.