# R is a relation over P(S): R = {(C, D) ∈ P (S)^{2} : C ∩ E = D ∩ E} is R an Equivalence relation?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

given a group S,E ⊆ S . we shall define a relation R, over P(S):

R = {(C, D) ∈ P (S)^${2}$ : C ∩ E = D ∩ E}

I need to prove that this relation is a Equivalence relation, but I'm confused about the way this relation is defined.

help will be appreciated very much.

Comment: Deux subsets of $S$ are equivalent if and only if their intersections with $E$ are the same. Their is no room for imagination here: just apply the definition of an equivalence relation. You have three axioms to check.

Comment: yes, but i do not understand the def as 
R = {(C, D) ∈ P (S)^2 : C ∩ E = D ∩ E}

as P (S)^2 is what i find confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **any** function $f:X\to Y$ the relation $x\sim y\iff f(x)=f(y)$ is an equivalence relation on $X$. This is easy to prove. E.g. the fact that $\forall x\in X [f(x)=f(x)]$ already tells us immediately that the relation is reflexive. Also symmetry and transitivity are easy.

Prescribe function $f:\wp(S)\to\wp(S)$ by $C\mapsto C\cap E$ and apply.

Comment: we haven't learned functions yet, so this isn't relevant for me at the moment

Comment: Very surprising. You are dealing with relations right? A function $f:X\to Y$ is a relation $\subseteq X\times Y$ with a special property: for every $x\in X$ there is a unique $y\in Y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in f$. This $y$ is denoted as $f(x)$. Did you not learn functions on high-school? Like $\sin x$ and $x^2$. That knowledge/understanding is enough allready for this. If you haven't learned about functions yet then how to explain [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2593293/75923)?

Comment: have not learned function is the course "set theory" so using functions does not help with this question. and to your question - i have learned functions in high school and in university.

Comment: which is how i explain this.

Comment: It might be so that you are not "allowed" yet to use functions by answering this question on course. In that sense this answer is useless. But (and in my view much more important) no one forbids you to understand my answer. If you do then at least you are equipped to recognize lots of relations almost directly as equivalence relations.

Comment: Yes, only that I DON'T UNDERSTAND IT

Comment: Do you understand that the relation  $R=\{\langle x,y\rangle\mid f(x)=f(y)\}$ is reflexive? (that is $xRx$ is true for every $x$)

Comment: not helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

An equivalence relation on a set $X$ is a subset $R$ of $X\times X$ satisfying three axioms:

- reflexivity: for any $x\in X$, $(x,x)\in R$
- symmetry: for any $x,y\in X$, if $(x,y)\in R$ then $(y,x)\in R$
- transitivity: for any $x,y,z\in X$, if $(x,y), (y,z)\in R$ , then $(x,z)\in R$.

For any $x,y\in X$, in general, we write $x R y$ or $x\sim_R y$ instead of $(x,y)\in R$. You may now relate the previous definition to the definition I suppose you know.

In your case, this translates as follows: for any two subsets $C,D$ of $S$, we have $C \sim_R  D$ if and only if $C\cap E=D\cap E$. Nothing more, nothing less.

I let you check that you get indeed an equivalence relation.